# BOX v2 API - Upload a file without oauth

Tags: box-api

Is it possible to upload a file via the Box V2 API without requiring the user to login. I don't want to have to make my users create Box accounts - is it possible for them to upload a file using my account, or perhaps the API key instead of OAuth?

Comment: Upload to what? Your box account?

Comment: Yes, to my box account, but from essentially an anonymous user (they're authenticated through my app's front end).

Answer (score 0):

OAuth works by exchanging login credentials for an access token and refresh token. If you persist your access token and allow your users to submit requests using that access token, that would be equivalent of the user being logged in under your account.

Please note that the Box V2 access tokens only have a lifetime of an hour. So after that time, you will need to refresh it using the refresh token.

Comment: How can we do upload/download files with access token??

Answer (score 0):

What about enabling uploads by email? Each folder will have a unique (and hard to guess) email address that you can send emails with attachments to. If you give that email address to users, they can upload that way.